# In which thread android viewmodel runs?

Tags: android

I am a beginner in Android data binding.In mvvm Architecture patter when we write code in viewmodel.In which thread those are running in main thread or seperate thread.

Comment: Viewmodel is Lifecycle aware class which is associated with UI.

Comment: On Main UI thread.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check using `Thread.currentThread()` method

In onCreate Method of Activity put log

```
Log.d(TAG, Thread.currentThread());
```

In constructor of Viewmodel put another log

```
Log.d(TAG, Thread.currentThread());
```

You will see the same thread Id.
Another example is when you try to perform db or network operation in viewmodel without using AsyncTask, Thread or RxJava it throw an Exception that Cannot perform operation on MainThread.

I hope this will help you

Comment: In case of retrofit API calls it's not showing any error

Comment: because that library handles threading and tons of problems itself.

Answer (score 3):

Viewmodel is Lifecycle aware class which is associated with UI. So the answer is Main UI Thread.